# CakePHP how to connect DynamoDB using entity?

Tags: cakephp, amazon-dynamodb, cakephp-4.x

I am using cakephp version 4.x. I am trying to dynamoDB with cakephp using entity.

I have created Model/Entity/Product.php , and used below code to connect dynamodb.

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;
use Aws\DynamoDb\Marshaler;
use Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException;

class Shop extends Entity
{
    static protected $dynamodb;
    
    public function connectDynamoDB()
    {
     
        $sdk = new \Aws\Sdk([
            'credentials' => [
                'key' => SHOP_DYNAMODB_ACCESS_ID,
                'secret' => SHOP_DYNAMODB_ACCESS_KEY,
            ],
            'region' => SHOP_DYNAMODB_REGION,
            'version' => 'latest',
        ]);

        return $this::$dynamodb = $sdk->createDynamoDb();
    }
}
```

How can I use this function connectDynamoDB in my ProductsController ? Is it possible ?

Comment: That should most likely not be in an entity in the first place. Ask yourself what exactly you actually want to do with that DynamoDB instance, and to which context its usage is related to.

Comment: @ndm I have a product list in dynamodb,I just want to fetch data using cakephp. I have lack of knowledge about dynamodb connection with cakephp. First time I am going to integrate it. Would you please give me an instruction where should I connection dynamodb? First I thought I will create a simply Connection in controller. I really confused.

Comment: I would assume your shop data is in DynamoDB too then, not just the product data? Maybe even _all_ your data is in DynamoDB?

Comment: @ndm Yes, you are right, I have no any other data source without DynamoDB.